# Piping data from FFPlay requires me to cat the pipe for the program to start

Tags: bash, shell-script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ICECASTURL=$1

nohup ffplay -autoexit \
             -nodisp \
             -i $ICECASTURL -af astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level \
              &> /tmp/stats &
```

This runs and waits. When I finally cat /tmp/stats

The program begins playing and sending the output to the pipe. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: replace the `&> /tmp/stats` with `1<>/tmp/stats 2>&1`. This may still block after a while if you don't cat the other end of the pipe (after `ffplay` has written ~64k of data to it). Even better, don't use a fifo but a regular file, and run `tail -f` on it.

Comment: I can do that but the file size is limited to 100mb and if i delete it ffplay does not start a new one.